# SMSDo Error when try to use counter variable i as vector index in loop

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I try to evaluate the following code, but I get
"Error during numerical evaluation of expression with random numbers."
Expression contains parts that canot be evaluated.
Messages:  `{Part::pkspec1,Part::pkspec1}`
Expression:   `{Sin[{$V[2,1],$V[3,1],$V[4,1]}[[$V[6,1]]]]}`

Code

```
Get["AceGen`"];
DIM = 3;
SMSInitialize["test", "Language" -> "C"];
SMSModule["Test", Real[x$$, xvec$$[DIM], y$$]];
x ⊢ SMSReal[x$$];
xvec ⊢ SMSReal[Table[xvec$$[i], {i, 1, DIM}]];

y ⫤ 0;
SMSDo[ 
  z ⊨ Sin[xvec[[i]]]; (* Error! *)
     (* z⊨Sin[x^i]; *) (* no! error *)
     y ⊣ y + (z + i/z)^i;
  , {i, 1, DIM, 1, y}];
SMSExport[y, y$$];
SMSWrite[];
FilePrint["test.c"]
```

To my understanding, in `xvec[[i]]` the counter `i` is represented in the error message as `$V[6,1]`. But the `$V` is a vector of real variables. So somehow, the loop counter `i` gets a real variable?

The above code is just a small modification of the example given in the AceGen manual Section "Mathematica Syntax - Acegen Syntax", "Example 3: Loops (Do construct)".
That example works for me and the loop counter gets an `int i4`.

Any help appreciated.

rcontinuum

Comment: To convert the special symbols in the code, you may want to try this tool: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/1871

Comment: You cannot use `[[i]]`, since `i` isn't integer buit a AceGen symbol, you can use either `SMSPart[xvec,i]` or you can read directly from imput `SMSReal[xvec$$[i]]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BHudobivnik